# how to change owner of sudoer file in centos that has been mistakenly changed to nonexisting user

Tags: chown, sudoers

i mistakenly changed ownership of /etc/sudoers file to a non-existing user, and now i can't revert it back nor do anything about it.

how can i force it to change the owner to root?

-r--r----- 1 755 1417 Dec 12 12:39 sudoers

Comment: You'll need to become `root` through any other non-`sudo` method (login as `root`, use `su -`, `ssh root@hostname`, etc...). `sudo` is broken in this configuration, as you've probably noticed...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an operating system question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] pages. It is more suitable for [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this by booting into single user mode and then chmod back to 0440.